Binding a nested object using FromForm
I have been able to properly bind a complex object to my model from a form but I am struggling for one item in particular and it is not making sense why it wont work as I have repeated the same logic for other examples to this one so I am scratching my head why this isnt working as expected. My axios request is as follows:
  const submit = () => {
let form = new FormData();

//state details
form.append('state_details.state_id' , JSON.stringify(stateModel.value!.state_id!))
programModel.value!.forEach((program : Program, index : number) => {form.append('state_details.program_details['+index+'].program_dd', JSON.stringify(program.program_dd))})
stateContactModel.value!.forEach((stateContact : User, index : number) => {form.append('state_details.state_contacts['+index+'].internal_user_number', JSON.stringify(stateContact.internal_user_number))})

//actuarial firm details
form.append('actuarial_firm_details.firm_dd' , JSON.stringify(actuarialFirmModel.value!.firm_dd))
form.append('actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details' , hasRiskMitigationModel.value.value)
signingActuaryModel.value!.forEach((actuary : User, index : number) => {form.append('actuarial_firm_details.signing_actuaries['+ index +'].internal_user_number', JSON.stringify(actuary.internal_user_number))})


api.post('/CertificationReview', form, config).then(response => {

})

}
My models are as follows:
public class AddCertificationReviewDTO
{

    [ModelBinder(Name = "state_details")]
    [Required]
    public required StateDTO StateDetails {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "actuarial_firm_details")]
    [Required]
    public required ActuarialFirmDTO ActuarialFirmDetails {get; set;}

}

public class ActuarialFirmDTO 
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "firm_dd")]
    [Required]
    public required int FirmDd {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "firm_name")]
    public string? FirmName {get; set;}
    
    [ModelBinder(Name = "actuary_details")]
    [Required]
    [Length(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter atleast 1 signing actuary.")]
    public required List<UserDTO> ActuaryDetails {get; set;}
}

public class UserDTO {
    [ModelBinder(Name = "internal_user_number")]
    [Required]
    public required int InternalUserNumber {get; set;}

}
public class StateDTO {
    [ModelBinder(Name = "state_id")]
    [Required]
    public required int StateId {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "entity_name")]
    public string? EntityName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "entity_abbreviation")]
    public string? EntityAbbreviation {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "program_details")]
    [Required]
    [Length(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter atleast 1 program.")]
    public required List<ProgramDTO> ProgramDetails {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "state_contacts")]
    [Required]
    [Length(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter atleast 1 contact.")]
    public required List<UserDTO> StateContacts {get; set;}
}

public class ProgramDTO {
    [ModelBinder(Name = "program_dd")]
    [Required]
    public required int ProgramDD {get; set;}
    
    [ModelBinder(Name = "program_name")]
    public string? ProgramName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "program_short_name")]
    public string? ProgramShortName {get; set;}
}

I have followed the same logic for my actuarial firm model as i did for my state_details by appending the array to the form and it works for state contacts and programs but when i get to my actuarial firm model it fails always saying request failed in the response
"errors": {
    "actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details": [
        "Please enter atleast 1 signing actuary."
    ]
}

The models are setup exactly the same so unsure why it wouldnt work. Also, my payload does show the following:
state_details.state_id: 2

state_details.program_details[0].program_dd: 158

state_details.state_contacts[0].internal_user_number: 660

state_details.state_contacts[1].internal_user_number: 661

actuarial_firm_details.firm_dd: 4

actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details: false

actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details[0].internal_user_number: 1646

actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details[1].internal_user_number: 1673


I can't reproduce your problem but it is clear that the error is in hasRiskMitigationModel.value.value. According to your description and you don't show directly the ProgramDetails and StateContacts, you could check the log in the method to see more details.

I believe it is due to you were sending the wrong value which your ActuaryDetails expects an array: actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details: false. Remove that should able to resolve the issue. While your front-end code didn't show us how you are building the array actuarial_firm_details.actuary_details[0] and so on.
